# Simplifying a QPainterPath to an outline

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I'm creating a custom drawing application using a `QGraphicsScene` in PySide - I want to be able to draw complex shapes and have the user interact with them via mouse. To accomplish this I created a custom `QGraphicsItem` called `Node` that defines its shape by returning a `QPainterPath` object. The graphics scene uses this shape to decide when the mouse has entered the object. In the objects `paint` method I simply draw the path using a `QPainter`.

```
import math
import sys
import weakref
from numpy import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *


class Node(QGraphicsItem):
    Type = QGraphicsItem.UserType+1

    def __init__(self, graphWidget, line):

        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.line = line
        self.graph = weakref.ref(graphWidget)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.newPos = QPointF()
        self.setZValue(-1)

    def boundingRect(self):
        adjust = 10.0
        return QRectF(self.line[0][0]-adjust, self.line[0][1]-adjust, 2*adjust + self.line[1][0]-self.line[0][0]+100,2*adjust+self.line[1][2]-self.line[0][3]+100)

    def shape(self):
        (x0,y0), (xn,yn) = p0, pn = self.line
        dx,dy = xn-x0, yn-y0
        dV = array([dx,dy])
        mag_dV = linalg.norm(dV)
        radius = 10
        rotation = array( [[0,-1],[1,0]])

        v = dot(rotation, dV) * radius / mag_dV

        startAngle = arctan2(*v) * 180/pi + 90


        path = QPainterPath()
        path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)
        path.moveTo(*p0 - v)
        path.addEllipse( x0-radius, y0-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius)
        path.moveTo(*p0+v)

        path.lineTo( QPoint(*pn+v))

        path.arcTo( xn - radius, yn-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius, startAngle+180, 180)


        path.lineTo(QPoint(*p0-v))

        return path.simplified()

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black))
        painter.setBrush(Qt.darkGray)
        painter.drawPath(self.shape())


class GraphWidget(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

        self.timerId = 0

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        scene.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        scene.setSceneRect(-200,-200,400,400)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.centerNode = Node(self, [[-100,-100],[0,-70]])
        scene.addItem(self.centerNode)

        self.centerNode.setPos(0,0)
        self.scale(0.8,0.8)
        self.setMinimumSize(400,400)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Elastic Nodes"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qsrand(QTime(0,0,0).secsTo(QTime.currentTime()))

    widget = GraphWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The issue I have is how to make the polygon into one solid shape. An example shape is this rectangle with rounded ends:

[image: desired drawing]

When I draw the rounded end with an ellipse instead of an arc, I get this:

[image: actual drawing with inner paths showing and alternating fill]

What I want to achieve is that the paths contained inside the shape of the polygon are gone and all I have is an outline of the entire shape, filled with a solid color. I also want to get rid of the alternating fill that you see. This would ostensibly allow me to create arbitrary polygons without calculating every exact angle and intersection point.

What I have tried so far:

The first thing I tried was to use `path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)`, which is supposed to make all inner spaces filled as opposed to having alternating color. This doesn't seem to do anything to change the outcome however.

The second thing I tried was use 'path.simplified()', which is supposed to do precisely what I am asking. The results of this command are:

[image: inner paths after running <code>path.simplified()</code>]

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Instead of drawing an ellipse, you could use an arc in the same way you are drawing the right extremity of your shape

Comment: You are correct, I could use an arc. The issue is what if I want to make a more complex shape: for example imagine I wanted to make a second one of these shapes that was linked to the first one so that the ellipses on the end of each element were concentric. In order to draw the outline I now need to think about 2 orientations, I need to calculate line intersections and I need to measure the angle between twice as many vectors. It would be much more concise to use ellipses. I will edit the question to indicate that this is not the only shape I want to draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the solution to this problem is actually pretty simple: it matters which way you go around the shape.

The shape drawn above is basically a rectangle oriented along a line segment, with a circle at each end. To draw the rectangle you have to use individual line segments. In the original question, the rectangle outline was drawn counter-clockwise:

```
    path.lineTo(QPointF(*p0+v))
    path.lineTo(QPointF(*pn+v))
    path.lineTo(QPointF(*pn-v))
    path.lineTo(QPointF(*p0-v))
```

Which leads to the overlapped parts not being filled:

[image: image with rectangle outlined counter-clockwise]

If I instead draw the rectangles outline going clockwise, I don't have this problem.

```
    path.lineTo(QPointF(*pn-v))
    path.lineTo(QPointF(*pn+v))
    path.lineTo(QPointF(*p0+v))
    path.lineTo(QPointF(*p0-v))
```

results in :

[image: rectangle outline drawn clockwise]

So there you have it. Below is my final code, producing a nice compound line segment that is clickable and can be manipulated.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import math
import sys
import weakref
from numpy import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *



class Node(QGraphicsItem):
    Type = QGraphicsItem.UserType+1

    def __init__(self, graphWidget, line):

        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.line = line
        self.radius = 8

        if graphWidget != None:
            self.graph = weakref.ref(graphWidget)

        self.newPos = QPointF()
        self.setCacheMode(self.DeviceCoordinateCache)
        self.setZValue(-1)



    def boundingRect(self):
        adjust = 10.0
        x,y = array(self.line).transpose()
        rect = [min(x)-self.radius, min(y)-self.radius, max(x)-min(x)+2*self.radius, max(y)-min(y)+2*self.radius]

        return QRectF(*rect)

    def shape(self):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)

        radius =  self.radius
        rotation = array( [[0,-1],[1,0]])

        points = zip(self.line[0:-1], self.line[1:])

        for p0, pn in points:
            (x0,y0),(xn,yn) = p0,pn
            dx,dy = array(pn) - array(p0)

            dV = array([dx,dy])
            mag_dV = linalg.norm(dV)

            v = dot(rotation, dV) * radius / mag_dV

            #starting circle
            path.addEllipse(QRectF(x0-radius, y0-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius))
            #rectangular part
            path.moveTo(QPointF(*p0-v))
            path.lineTo(QPointF(*pn-v))
            path.lineTo(QPointF(*pn+v))
            path.lineTo(QPointF(*p0+v))

        path.moveTo(QPointF(*pn))
        path.addEllipse(QRectF(xn-radius, yn-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius))

        return path.simplified()


    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.darkGray)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.drawPath(self.shape())

    def setGraph(self, graph):
        self.graph = weakref.ref(graph)

class GraphWidget(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

        self.timerId = 0

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        scene.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        scene.setSceneRect(0,0,880,880)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorViewCenter)

        self.centerNode = Node(self, [[50,50],[200,100], [500, 100], [700,700]])
        scene.addItem(self.centerNode)


        self.centerNode.setPos(0,0)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,900,900)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Elastic Nodes"))



    def addItem(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.scene().addItem(item)
        item.setGraph(self)
        item.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qsrand(QTime(0,0,0).secsTo(QTime.currentTime()))

    widget = GraphWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```